# Replacing certain parts of a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of columns that represents months for different metrics. It was imported from a CSV. There are two issues: (1) The months start with '22-' and (2) some months end with .1 , .2 etc.

Here is the list:

```
months = ['22-Apr', '22-May', '22-Apr.1', '22-Apr.2']
```

Tried using `.replace` but I can't get it to remove only certain parts of the list

Comment: `months = [month[3:].split('.')[0] for month in months]`

Comment: ...or rather `month[3:6]` to get rid of the occasionnal `.1`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit to provide a solid example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among others, you could `split` by `'-'` and get the second part, then by `'.'` and get the first part. The latter will work even if there is no `'.'` in the string.

```
>>> months = ['22-Apr', '22-May', '22-Apr.1', '22-Apr.2']
>>> [s.split("-")[1].split(".")[0] for s in months]
['Apr', 'May', 'Apr', 'Apr']
```

The `[1]` means that this will work only if there is *always* a year-part present, but it does not matter if that has 2 or 4 digits.

Comment: You may wish to limit the number of times your calls to `str.split` have to work: `[s.split("-", 1)[1].split(".", 1)[0] for s in months]`